# hashing a dictionary using sha256

Tags: python, python-3.x

While executing this line of code:

```
DIGEST = sha256(json.dumps(CONFIG.__dict__, sort_keys=True)).hexdigest()
```

I got this error:

> Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing

Later I changed it to:

```
DIGEST = sha256(json.dumps(CONFIG.__dict__, encoding='utf-8', sort_keys=True)).hexdigest()
```

But doing that couldn't fix the error.
Any solution for the same could be of great help.

Comment: Dupe: [How to correct TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing?](//stackoverflow.com/q/7585307)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
DIGEST = sha256(json.dumps(CONFIG.__dict__,sort_keys=True).encode('utf8')).hexdigest()
```

should work.